# Multiple database operations from sql query

Tags: android

I have two instances of `SQLiteDatabase` database. And I need to copy data from one to another.
I need to execute this query:

```
INSERT INTO `toDB`.`tableName` SELECT * FROM `fromDB`.`tableName`
```

so, How can I do this my database instances? How to replace toDB and fromDB ?

Comment: do you need to copy from one table to another with in the same database?

Comment: copy one table from first database to the second database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never tried that but it should work this way:

you have to [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) the other database at SQLite level so sqlite can access it directly.

For example you open the database that shall be the `toDB` and you issue the following command (via `execSQL`)

```
ATTACH DATABASE '/data/data/your.package/databases/dbname.db' AS fromDB
```

you should have access to the other database now and can do

```
INSERT INTO main.tableName SELECT * FROM fromDbB.tableName
```

the database you opened originally has the name "main" automatically.

You can and should get the path to your databases via [Context#getDatabasePath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) since there is no guarantee that this path is the same on all devices.

Comment: but can you access database of other apps with **/data/data/...**?

Comment: If the database file has the right permissions yes: [MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) but usually no.

Comment: Fortunately my database storages in sdcard, so this method has worked. Thanks. But I still want to know if there is more optimal method

Comment: you can copy the database file to internal storage and use it from there instead of importing it. But for copying data from db to db that should be the fastest you can do.

Comment: in my case I dont need it. I need to import that table, change table structure and put into my application's database. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this as following:

> ```
>     DatabaseHelper dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.create(CMOSApplication.getInstance());
>     SQLiteDatabase db = null;
>     try {
>         db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
>         db.execSQL("attach database ? as oldDB",
>                 new String[] { CMOSApplication.getInstance().getDatabasePath("cmos_database").getPath() });
>         db.execSQL("insert into task select * from oldDB.task");
>     } catch (SQLException e) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     } finally {
>         if(db != null){
>             try {
>                 db.execSQL("detach oldDB");
>             } catch (SQLException e) {
>                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```